# Codeigniter Using ion Auth Library in more than website

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Dears,

I am trying to use ion auth in more than website, all of thing is working good except when I am logged in one site, the other sites will be logged in automatically, 
So, their are an issue with same session or cookie name, I tried to find where can I change it but can't :(

Can you please help!

Comment: in application/config/config - change the cookie name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cartalot :) That was so simple